# How is a K8s POD Implemented and what is its core implementation components?

Tags: kubernetes

I have read a lot about K8s PODs. 
Most of the answers are logical in nature.
Even on k8s.io the definition of a POD is as follows:

*A Pod is the basic building block of Kubernetes–the smallest and simplest unit in the Kubernetes object model that you create or deploy. A Pod represents a running process on your cluster.*

I would like to know what the relationship of a K8s POD is with its core implementation components.

Comment: What do you mean by core implementation components?

Comment: A search in your favourite search engine for `kubernetes vs docker` should prove enlightening. As it stands, this question is too broad and ill-defined to have a specific *correct* answer, and as such is a bad fit for SO.

Comment: K8s vs Docker? are you sure you would advise such a comparison? K8s vs Openshift, maybe...K8s vs Docker...that in itself maybe why this is a good question. With regard to broadness...the question is extremely specific in its nature. It asks anyone out there, how a POD is implemented. How much more specific could a question get?

Comment: A POD is a group (usually 1, but sometimes more) of containers guaranteed to run on the same physical host with shared access to resources such as storage and network. Usually implemented with docker, but can operate with other containerization technologies. So the key to understanding "what" a POD is, is understanding the containerization on which it is built (and how multiple containers can share these resources). Understanding k8s in terms of docker would be a great place to start looking, because IMO, docker is the most accessible and well-documented of the container-techs.

Comment: Thank you _spender_. Since the *mainstay* of a lot of container technology at their core use Linux _namespace_ and _cgroups_ would it therefore be *fair* to say, that at its core, K8s PODs _usually_ (i stress usually) would be an instance of Linux running containers. The fact that the POD itself is a container seems to me to indicate that it requires the enabling technology to run on. Now, before you mention LXC and CoreOs Rckt...yes I agree, there are others, but Docker was built around what is mentioned above.

Comment: Addendum::I mean, fair enough...the POD is a container...but it needs something to run on, whether it is using Docker, LXC or Rckt. right?

Comment: The POD is a *group* of containers that share stuff (including IIRC, the same network stack). Kubernetes orchestrates the deployment of these containers on some underlying container-tech, and configures the deployments according to some set of configured rules. As such, your containers will run in an environment guaranteed to fulfill these rules, or not be deployed (scheduled). Dependent on factors like auto-scaling, kubernetes may never be able to conjure up an environment where an ill-specified POD can run.

Comment: k8s is just pulling the levers of some other container tech, providing a consistent language to schedule containers and allowing for certain guarantees about the environment in which they run.

Comment: Thanks. Really good answers. I just read this: _Docker Inc. builds products that let you build and run containers on Linux, Windows and macOS._ so if we take Docker as the K8s container technology, then the levers are the implementation of K8s over Docker. Said _levers_, would then instantiate a POD, based on K8s implementation interacting with an implementation of Docker on Windows, or Linux or MacOs. Therefore, Linux is NOT the base component. The base component is the K8s codebase, that is the orchestrator with the POD mapping to one or more contrainers and as you say, the stuff they share.

Comment: Now its clear. :=) A POD is an extension of a container and the add-ons necessary to do the following: _Kubernetes is an open source container orchestration engine for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications_. Irrespective of the underlying container technology and the latter's dependence on its' stack of technologies.

Comment: Glad to help... ( I stand by my close vote though :) )

Comment: I am sure you do re: stand-by your vote. I don't mind and in-fact I appreciate your answers even more, as you have shown perseverance and flexibility. You never know, that perseverance might pay off, if newbies to K8s etc. are to read your answers. For sure it has for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to answer the question is to look at the K8s codebase, given the answers above:
[image]

Here is a snapshot of the Pod*.go listings in the current snapshot of the K8s project. If you look in the *container/runtime.go* you will see the following:

[image]

Perhaps even more importantly, is the *runtime.go* interface comments:
[image]

So, it becomes crystal clear, that the runtime of K8s depends on an underlying container runtime that implements the interface for the runtime. In the runtime live the Pods:
[image]

Therefore, the truth of the answer to the question:
**Q> How is a K8s POD Implemented and what is its core implementation components?**
Ans: A K8s Pod is a struct within the K8s runtime-interface that references a group of containers; the core implementation on which a Pod relies is the K8s container-runtime interface that in turn binds to a container-runtime implementation, of which there are many: 
https://joejulian.name/post/kubernetes-container-engine-comparison/